# CANNON.js: Visual representation of a RigidBody

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, cannon.js

I have a `THREE.js` Scene where Objects have physcis applied to them using `CANNON.js`. The RigidBody is initialized like so:

```
let shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1, 1, 1));
let body = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 5,
    shape: shape
});
```

I would like to have a visual representation of the `CANNON.Body` using my `THREE.Scene`.

**How do I visually represent a RigidBody?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to debug render Cannon.js physics objects in Three.js is probably using the [THREE.CannonDebugRenderer](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/tree/master/tools/threejs).

Comment: Though it doesn't fully fit my needs, I'll extract the necessary code from that example. Thanks for the info, since most stuff is somewhat hard to find in these libraries.

Comment: I've created very simple TypeScript Definition file for this script. For anyone needing this, see my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/three-cannondebugrenderer)